# Should I use singular or plural when the subject is a bag of apples?

Tags: verb-agreement

I'm wondering which one is correct:

A bag of apples weighs 25 pounds.

A bag of apples weigh 25 pounds.

A bowl of noodles is enough.

A bowl of noodles are enough.

I'm confused, should I take ‘a bag of apples’ as a whole thing and use a singular verb， or put the emphasis on the amount of apples and use a plural verb.

Comment: If you're not sure about the form of the verb, try to remove descriptive elements from the sentence, such as "of apples", so you're left with "A bag weighs 25 pounds."

Answer (score 1):

1. The **apples** [in each bag] weigh 25 lbs
2. Each **bag** [of apples] weighs 25 lbs.
3. *A bag of apples* **weighs** 25 lbs

The subject "a bag of apples" requires the singular verb. Likewise the item that contains the noodles, which could be a bowl, a pot, a packet, a box etc.  if it is singular the verb that follows must also be singular

1. **A bowl** of noodles **is** enough
2. **Two** bowls [of noodles] **are** enough.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should go with the singular form, when the quantifier is single, such as a set of, a bag of. However, if the quantifier is plural,  for instance, sets of, the verb followed is plural.

Comment: Precisely, 'a bag of ...' and 'a bowl of' ... are _**pseudo-partitives** subset container structures_  [[Matushansky et al](http://www.trees-and-lambdas.info/matushansky/Downloads/Pseudo-partitive-syntax-EGR-JZ.pdf)], not the metaphorical look-alikes _fuzzy quantifiers_ (piles of money, shedloads of ambition ...). Admittedly, quantities are still not being precisely measured in pseudo-partitives. However, with container pseudo-partitives, the container noun (bag, bowl, glass, cup, amphora, barrel ...) is what governs agreement. _A bag of apples weighs_ ... but _Two bags of apples weigh_ ....